# Java : how to call methods with the same name in different objects instantiated from different classes?

Tags: java, android, class, instance, instantiation

I think that my question is not very clear :) Here is my problem (in more details):

I have got several objects (lets say objA, objB, objC, etc...) which are instances from different classes (lets say ClassA, ClassB, ClassC... respectively).

These objects A, B, C,..., call the same object (let's call it jsonConnector, instance of JsonConnector class) and I want then this jsonConnector to call the updateUI() method of the object by which it has been created.

Code in my ClassX (ClassA, ClassB, etc...) class:

```
JsonConnector jsonConnector = new JsonConnector(this);
```

Constructor of my JsonConnector class:

```
private Object callingObject;

public JsonConnector(Object aCallingObject) {

 callingObject = aCallingObject
}
```

Somewhere in my JsonConnector class, I want to do:

```
aCallingObject.updateUI();
```

but I have got a compiling error "The method updateUI() is undefined for the type Object"

I could do :

```
String callingClassName = callingObject.getClass().getSimpleName();

if(callingClassName == "ClassA")
{
((ClassA)aCallingObject).updateUI();
}
else if(callingClassName == "ClassB")
{
((ClassB)aCallingObject).updateUI();
}
else if...
```

But it I don't want to write 100 'else if' statements !

Anybody knows how I can do ?

Thanks !!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you could program to an interface.

```
public interface GuiUpdate
{
   void UpdateUI() ;
}
//do the same for classes that updates a gui. 
public class ClassA implements GuiUpdate
```

Do you have control over JsonConnector? If so, inject the object references:

```
public JsonConnector(GuiUpdate updater)
```

To add, this means you can simply do the following in a subsequent method, polymorphism and abstraction at its finest:

```
  updater.UpdateUI() ;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! It works like a charm. What's about if I want to access a int variable which has a different value in the different classA, classB,...objects ? For exemple if I want to get updater.classIntValue ? (classIntValue being an instance int variable of the classes A, B...) Thanks.

Comment: @Regis_AG You should be able to add that method to your interface as well.. `updater.getImportantInteger()`

Answer (score 1):

You can create an `interface`, which contains the `updateUI` method.

Make sure that all of those objects `implement` that `interface`.

Then pass them to the `JsonConnector` using `MyInterface` instead of `Object`:

```
private CalleeInterface callingObject;

public JsonConnector(CalleeInterface aCallingObject) {

  callingObject = aCallingObject
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use reflection. But don't use it if you have other solutions.

```
callingObject.getClass().getMethod("updateUI").invoke(callingObject);
```

Comment: I have not fully tried your solution but it seems that it works. I will nevertheless use an "Interface" as it seems a more standard solution. Thanks.